# Setting a VerneMq cluster (VBox

Tags: cluster-computing, mqtt, mqtt-vernemq

My idea is to install a VerneMQ cluster on test environment (no need of security here).
I installed VerneMq(1.4.1) on 2 different VMs on Virtual Box (Ubuntu 16).
I started the 2 instances of VerneMQ and their status are well "Active".
I try to do (in both side)

```
sudo vmq-admin cluster join discovery-node=192.168.56.103:44000
```

But I got all the time this error

```
Couldn't join cluster due to not_reachable
```

As there is no need of security for the moment I flushed the IPtables with

```
sudo iptables -F
sudo iptables -X
sudo iptables -t nat -F
sudo iptables -t nat -X
sudo iptables -t mangle -F
sudo iptables -t mangle -X
sudo iptables -P INPUT ACCEPT
sudo iptables -P FORWARD ACCEPT
sudo iptables -P OUTPUT ACCEPT
```

and even stopped the firewall

```
sudo ufw disable
```

I also tried to ping and check the port with nmap (I changed the port to 44000 in case of....):

```
sudo nmap 192.168.56.103 -p 44000
```

I got all the result (for nmap) :

```
PORT      STATE SERVICE
44000/tcp open  unknown
```

Although all that I continue to get the error

```
Couldn't join cluster due to not_reachable
```

Thanks for the one that have an idea

Answer (score 0):

Please review the notes on cluster communication in the docs: 
https://vernemq.com/docs/clustering/communication.html

You'll want to configure the following config values in the vernemq.conf. (the `port_range` one is so that you can configure any firewall between the nodes)

```
    erlang.distribution.port_range.minimum = 6000
    erlang.distribution.port_range.maximum = 7999

    listener.vmq.clustering = (internal-ip):44053
```

Btw: you don't need to add the port in the `cluster join` command for the discovery-node

EDIT:

- Do you use the same `distributed_cookie` for both nodes?
- Does port 4369 (EPMD default port) allow incoming requests on both
  nodes?

Comment: Hello André, Sorry to not have confirmed these points there, but Yes I seen this page, and updated the conf file (restart after change). I just modified the port, but setting back the initial value doesn't change the problem, thx

Comment: I confirm you that the distributed_cookie is the same for both VerneMq instances, Also, the 4369 port is accessible because the firewall is simply shut down (no security needed in this test environment); thx again